# $P[X<Y,a<\min(X,Y)<b]=P[X<Y,a<X<b]$

Tags: probability

What properties of $P$ should be used to prove that $P[X<Y,a<\min(X,Y)<b]=P[X<Y,a<X<b]$?

I found that (let $S:=\min(X<Y)$):

$\begin{align}P[X<Y,a<S<b]&=\sum\limits_{i=0,1} P[X<Y,a<S<b\mid S=i]P[S=i]\\
&=P[X<Y,a<Y<b\mid S=0]P[S=0] + P[X<Y,a<X<b\mid S=1]P[S=1]\\
&=P[X<Y,a<X<b\mid S=1]P[S=1]\\
&=P[X<Y, a<X<b]
\end{align}$

Comment: Just verify that the events on the two sides are one and the same! When $X<Y$ we have $\min (X,Y)=X$.

Answer (score 1):

The events (sets, really) are just the same. So no property of $P$ is needed besides it being a function (i.e. one-valued).

If $X < Y$ then it's clear the minimum will be $X$, so the combined condition can be simplified.